# How to have full completion in a run application dialog?

Tags: bash, zsh, xfce, autocomplete

I've configured XFCE to execute `gmrun` as run dialog (Alt-F2). It works great with completion on commands but does not propose completion on arguments.

How to set up a run dialog with full bash/zsh like autocompletion capabilities?

Comment: spawn a terminal with bash or zsh in it.

Comment: not really because the completion would require a large terminal, in gmrun the completion proposals are scrollable choice boxes

Comment: i doubt one exists, especially if you want the completion bash or zsh would normally present.